# find highest key with value from Object

Tags: javascript, object

Trying to get the highest value along with its key from a javascript object.  I tried different solutions such as Object.key or Object.entries but can't seem to find a way, any thoughts.

```
let dates = {
  '2021-08-06': 39,
  '2021-08-07': 0,
  '2021-08-08': 0,
  '2021-08-09': 149,
  '2021-08-10': 174,
  '2021-08-11': 231,
  '2021-08-12': 300,
}
```

previous attempts I can get the value by using object.keys but for some reason either I am drawing a blank or something but I cant bring its key back.

This previous solution just gets the min and highest number, but how can i bring back its corresponding key?

```
  let arr = Object.keys( dates ).map(function ( key ) { return d[key]; });
  let max = Math.max.apply( null, arr );
  let maxKey, maxValue = 0;

  for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(dates)) {
    if(value > max) {
      maxValue = value;
      maxKey = key;
    }
  }

  console.log(maxKey,maxValue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Sort Object.entries on the value, then return the first "entry"

The result will be in the form `["key", value]`

```js
let dates = {
  '2021-08-06': 39,
  '2021-08-07': 0,
  '2021-08-08': 0,
  '2021-08-09': 149,
  '2021-08-10': 174,
  '2021-08-11': 231,
  '2021-08-12': 300
}
const result = Object.entries(dates).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a)[0];
console.log(result);
```

Perhaps the ES6 goodness scares people into downvoting, here is a less modern approach (exactly the same semantics though)

```js
let dates = {
  '2021-08-06': 39,
  '2021-08-07': 0,
  '2021-08-08': 0,
  '2021-08-09': 149,
  '2021-08-10': 174,
  '2021-08-11': 231,
  '2021-08-12': 300
}
const result = Object.entries(dates).sort(function(a, b) {
  return b[1] - a[1];
})[0];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger - probably because I haven't said anything :p

Comment: @PeterSeliger - I don't really care though. See, there's a disease online - social media brings out the worst in people, and I think some come here, and behave the same way

Comment: why :p I think the OP knows about Object.entries already

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
Object.entries(dates).sort((a, b) => {
  return b[1] - a[1]
})[0]
```

to get the highest value along with its key in an array.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - probably one in the same person :D

Comment: How does this work since `a` and `b` are arrays?

Comment: I edited so it actually works, sorry for any inconvenience caused